# How to Convert two columns of CSV files to consecutive integers?

Tags: shell, csv

Hello say I have this file file1.csv and it has 2 columns a and b which are both 22 char strings. It looks like something like this:

```
hWcYwgRKOD77hfm1oKE0IA,5HleiJXMsFkGEsr8Jqr3Ug
hWcYwgRKOD77hfm1oKE0IA,rCDlYd2WHJuiT05sYGxaVA
65q0c2Iw03B8eSuHHTETHw,G40NUD0/op+13yjzBw+hrw
65q0c2Iw03B8eSuHHTETHw,1u8UW/cQ4i1vbSF9wvzu3w
...
```

And I would like to convert the a, b columns into consecutive integers like:

```
1,1
1,2
2,3
2,4
```

Does anyone know how can I do it? I am using Ubuntu 12.04 by the way

And what if I have another file file2.csv with column a' and b'. And is there any way to do the same thing to file2 and if "hWcYwgRKOD77hfm1oKE0IA" is 1 in file1 then "hWcYwgRKOD77hfm1oKE0IA" is 1 in file2 if it appears. Same for column b and b'. And I would like to have single output from those two files: result1.csv and result2.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ if ($1 in a) { $1 = a[$1] } else { $1 = a[$1] = ++x } 
                    if ($2 in b) { $2 = b[$2] } else { $2 = b[$2] = ++y } } 1' file
```

Or perhaps simpler but may be less efficient:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '!($1 in a) { a[$1] = ++x } { $1 = a[$1] }
                  !($2 in b) { b[$2] = ++y } { $2 = b[$2] } 1' file
```

Or dynamic to any number of columns:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
                        if ((i, $i) in a) { $i = a[i, $i] }
                                     else { $i = a[i, $i] = ++x[i] } } 1' file
```

Which is also similar to

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
                    if (!((i, $i) in a)) a[i, $i] = ++x[i]
                    $i = a[i, $i] } } 1' file
```

Output:

```
1,1
1,2
2,3
2,4
```

#### UPDATE

To apply on two files, try:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ if ($1 in a) { $1 = a[$1] } else { $1 = a[$1] = ++x } 
                    if ($2 in b) { $2 = b[$2] } else { $2 = b[$2] = ++y } 
                    print > "result_" FILENAME }' file1 file2
```

#### UPDATE 02

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '!($1 in a) { a[$1] = ++x } !($2 in b) { b[$2] = ++y }
                  { print $1, $2, a[$1], b[$2] }' file
```

Output:

```
hWcYwgRKOD77hfm1oKE0IA,5HleiJXMsFkGEsr8Jqr3Ug,1,1
hWcYwgRKOD77hfm1oKE0IA,rCDlYd2WHJuiT05sYGxaVA,1,2
65q0c2Iw03B8eSuHHTETHw,G40NUD0/op+13yjzBw+hrw,2,3
65q0c2Iw03B8eSuHHTETHw,1u8UW/cQ4i1vbSF9wvzu3w,2,4
```

File by file version:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '!($1 in a) { a[$1] = ++x } !($2 in b) { b[$2] = ++y }
                  { print $1, $2, a[$1], b[$2] > "result_" FILENAME }' file1 file2
```

Comment: Hi thank you again for the help yesterday. But now I got a new question: What if I want to keep the column A B A' B' can I convert like "hWcYwgRKOD77hfm1oKE0IA,5HleiJXMsFkGEsr8Jqr3Ug" to "hWcYwgRKOD77hfm1oKE0IA,5HleiJXMsFkGEsr8Jqr3Ug,1,1"?

Comment: @user3692521 The idea already kind of complicates it already. Is it ok if you ask it on another question? I mean post another question about it.

Comment: Sure here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274004 thank you so much!

Comment: @user3692521 I misread your question. I thought you were wanting to keep some columns selectively.

Comment: I just want to keep the original 2 columns and add the 2 new columns as columns 3 and 4